# How to send image stored in RMS to server in j2me?

Tags: post, java-me, rms

I want to send the image stored in the RMS to server. For that I have stored the captured image in the RMS. I can access it successfully and can show it over device, but when I used to send it to server, that time over the server only name of image appears but the image is not generating.

here is the line code that I am trying to use

```
    byte[] byteArrRec = LoadImagesFromRMS.objImageRecordStore.getRecord(recID);
    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrRec);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bin);                   
    int width = din.readInt();
    int height = din.readInt();
    int length = din.readInt();

    int[] rawImg = new int[width * height];

    for (int itemp = 0; itemp < length; itemp++) {
        rawImg[itemp] = din.readInt();
    }               
    Image tempImage = Image.createRGBImage(rawImg, width, height, false);
    byteArr = get_Byte_Array(tempImage);
    byteArr = get_Byte_Array(tempImage);
```

Then I have passed the byteArray using post method over the server.
     But the Image is not been generated, Did any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. First need to read all bytes from response and store in one variable (`bytearray`) of byte array. Then after that write this code
2. Create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from your byte array and then use `ImageIO` class to read image from that stream.

   > `InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray);`
   >
   > ```
   > BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
   > ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `HttpConnection` with the remote server, after creating connection , create a `DataOutputStream` variable associated with the `HttpConnection` variable. 
Now write byte array into that `DataOutputStream` variable and send it as `"POST"` method. If byte array's size is very big the try to send it in chunks..

Comment: I have already created HttpConnection with the remote server and can able to send the data over server successfully. The data with image which i am trying to send over server using post method is showing properly but only the image is not forming.